# Ubunutu doesn't recognize 3rd monitor

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display

I just installed Ubunutu 14.04, after the experimentation I did with previous version on virtual machines went smoothly.

I have 3 monitors - 2 connected to PCI-E graphic card (via DVI and HDMI), and 1 connected directly to the motherboard via DVI. When I finished the installation of the operation system, it recognized all 3 monitors, but it seems they were all considered as 1, since I couldn't extend the display, and the resolution was limited (they just showed the same picture as if they were one monitor). So I thought that I may be missing drivers... I went to AMD website to get drivers for my external graphic card (the one with the 2 monitors connected), which is a Radeon HD 5670.. I found the drivers on AMD.com after I couldn't find linux-compatible drivers on Gigabyte.com (which is my graphic card's manufacturer). I grabbed the driver from AMD.com, installed it, and it worked just fine, but only for my 2 monitors connected to that graphic card, but the 3rd monitor connected to the motherboard (Gigabyte GA-H67A-UD3H), is now black, and it doesn't show up on the Ubunutu's display settings at all.

I couldn't find any solution or idea to what's the problem is, searching the web.. all I could find is people with 2 monitors\1 graphic card which is not recognized well..

What can I do?